# SQL to find matching rate with effective date

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, I have a table of date-ordered records.  Here's a simplified version of it.

```
CREATE TABLE [SomeTrip] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TripDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [SomeTrip_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

For each of these records, there are a number of rates for various items that come into effect on the `EffectiveDate`.  Here's a simplified version of that table:

```
CREATE TABLE [SomeRates] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Rate1] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Rate2] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Rate3] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Rate4] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    CONSTRAINT [SomeRates_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Here's some sample data for these two tables:

```
INSERT INTO SomeRates (EffectiveDate, Rate1, Rate2, Rate3, Rate4) VALUES
('2016-01-01', 2016.1, 2016.2, 2016.3, 2016.4),
('2017-01-01', 2017.1, 2017.2, 2017.3, 2017.4),
('2018-01-01', 2018.1, 2018.2, 2018.3, 2018.4);

INSERT INTO SomeTrip (TripDate) VALUES ('2018-01-03'), ('2017-11-15'), ('2016-06-30');
```

If I want to select trips along with effective rates as of a known date, I could do the following query:

```
-- Select all trips and rate relative to a single date
select *
FROM SomeTrip
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SomeRates WHERE SomeRates.EffectiveDate <= '2017-12-15' ORDER BY SomeRates.EffectiveDate DESC) AS SomeRates ON 1=1;
```

This gives the following data:

```
ID  TripDate    ID  EffectiveDate  Rate1   Rate2   Rate3   Rate4
1   2018-01-03  2   2017-01-01     2017.1  2017.2  2017.3  2017.4
2   2017-11-15  2   2017-01-01     2017.1  2017.2  2017.3  2017.4
3   2016-06-30  2   2017-01-01     2017.1  2017.2  2017.3  2017.4
```

However, I want to display rates that were in effect at the given time RELATIVE TO THE TRIP.  (And in reality, I have lots of other calculations in the select that depend on the rates.)  A naive and syntactically incorrect attempt went something like this:

```
-- Select all trips and rate relative to the trip's TripDate
select *
FROM SomeTrip
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SomeRates WHERE SomeTrip.TripDate >= SomeRates.EffectiveDate ORDER BY SomeRates.EffectiveDate DESC) AS SomeRates ON 1=1;
```

The problem is that SQL Server does not allow access to the rows of SomeTrip from an inner query on SomeRates.

This is the result I'd like to see:

```
ID  TripDate    ID  EffectiveDate  Rate1   Rate2   Rate3   Rate4
1   2018-01-03  3   2018-01-01     2018.1  2018.2  2018.3  2018.4
2   2017-11-15  2   2017-01-01     2017.1  2017.2  2017.3  2017.4
3   2016-06-30  1   2016-01-01     2016.1  2016.2  2016.3  2016.4
```

I'm feeling like there should be some solution maybe using PARTITION, but I am not familiar enough with it to come up with something.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) is perfect for this type of problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTrip
 OUTER APPLY 
   (SELECT TOP 1 * 
      FROM SomeRates 
      WHERE SomeTrip.TripDate >= SomeRates.EffectiveDate 
      ORDER BY SomeRates.EffectiveDate DESC) AS SubQuery
```

Also it will save from you a world of hurt if you put indexes on the TripDate and EffectiveDate columns.

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks so much!  I had not come across `OUTER APPLY` before, and I doubt I could have thought of search terms that would have found it.  Future Googlers: [More info about APPLY on Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  I did not include indexes as I was trying to make the smallest test possible; an index on the effective date might not be needed if the SomeRates table can be read in one disk read, but definitely needed on SomeTrip.TripDate.